# Unable to click on the element on Microsoft Page

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on a particular element in a Microsoft UI,but was not able to click on it. Tried so many approaches using CSS,ID,Xpath but no luck.

Here I am trying to click on 'Authorize' button.

[![][1]][1]

Error is

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#accept-button"}

This is the HTML :

```
<button type="button" data-bi-area="PartnerInvitationButtons" data-bi-prodcat="PartnerInvitation" data-bi-scn="PartnerInvitationAcceptClicked" data-bi-view="PartnerInvitationComponent" id="accept-button" name="accept-button" class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary root-56" data-is-focusable="true"><div class="ms-Button-flexContainer flexContainer-48"><react-content style="display: none;"></react-content>
        Authorize
      </div>
```

Comment: Does it have an iframe within the page

Comment: Yes it does have iframe.

Comment: You need to switch to that frame first and then perform your action

Comment: Thanks Nishant! Worked now. Appreciate it.